# highcharts can't work in website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I'm a new by in javascript. I want to plot a stack bar chart by using highcharts in my website. I copy the demo code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/), then paste it in my php localhost, but there's no highcharts in my website. what's the problem?

**code↓**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#container").highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -30,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [9, 10, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [8, 5, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [7, 7, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <h2 align="center">HighCharts.js demo</h2>
  Where's the plot?<br>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the script that invokes jquery and make it load before the highcharts. This is necessary because Highcharts is built on top of jquery and without it loaded before the highcharts source, it will cause errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome! Highcharts is built on top of jquery, so it will give some errors if jquery was not loaded before